# Cordova deviceready not firing in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to build my hybrid app.
On Android my app is running quite fine. Now I was building it for iOS but my entire content that is wrapped inside

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  console.log('dashboard -> device ready');
  // copy database to the device
  DbAccess.copyDb();
}, false);
```

is not fired in iOS.

I tried it then with the iOS simulator

```
$ ionic emulate ios --livereload
```

and checked the console.log.

Result:

```
1     709252   log      deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
2     709253   log      Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

I followed the suggestions I found here and via Google but unfortunately without any success (removing ios and re-adding, etc)

My versions:

```
Cordova: 6.1.1
Ionic: 1.7.14
```

My Security setup in my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Inside my config.xml:

```
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

I really have no idea where I could go on to solve that bug. Maybe it is something with the Content-Security-Policy but I have no idea how to fix that.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit:
I wrapped my controller(s) now inside

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {...});
```

e.g.:

```
    var dashboardCtrl = function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaDevice, DbAccess) {
      console.log('dashboardCtrl');
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        console.log('dashboard -> platform ready');
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
          console.log('dashboard -> device ready');
          // copy database to the device
          DbAccess.copyDb();
        }, false);
      });
    };
    dashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaDevice', 'DbAccess'];
```

It still fails and throws the "deviceready" error in the console.log while I am testing it with the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ionic why you are manually using `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function ()` the `$ionicPlatform.ready` give you the same result as the 'deviceready' of the cordova, no need to call deviceready again.

Another thing, you should not put the ready function in custom function of the controller.  **should not** use like this

```
$scope.logInSubmit = function (details)  {}
```

or

```
var submit = function () {}
```

If you check the **sample of Ionic** you will get better idea of both the items (ex: ionic start myApp tabs)

In Ionic your code can be like this

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  console.log('dashboard -> device ready');
  //you can load your plugins or custom objects inside this device ready
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pyro!
I did not know that "document.addEventListener('deviceready', function ()" is already including "$ionicPlatform.ready"

Comment: @StefanBlattmann For the additional ref: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

Comment: If this answer helps you please tick the answer as correct. thanks

Comment: @Pyro What is wrong to use the ready function inside of a controller? If you want to do some plugin actions inside of a controller it is necessary to wait until the deveice is ready.

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach it is okay to use it inside any controller. i am saying it's not good to call inside any controller's custom function other than default function also updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I catch the event with

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
...
})
```

It works on a real device, I had never test on emulator.
I don't think that Content-Security-Policy is the reason that you don't get the event.

Comment: Thanks @simon-schüpbach!

I changed my code now (see my edited post) but it still fails in the simulator.

Comment: I added gap:// ready to my Content-Security-Policy and after that, everything works as expected.